# Drive.Files.Update - Uploading a new revision to maintain doc ID error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-drive-api

I'm trying to upload a new revision to an existing file (original file) and maintain the ID for that file.

I have the Google Drive API (v2) enabled in the Advanced Google Services. I have the script as a standalone script (not attached to a google doc or spreadsheet based on something I read that said the Drive.Files.Update doesn't work for those scripts).

On this line of code:

```
Drive.Files.update({
      title: currentFile.getName(), mimeType: currentFile.getMimeType()
}, originalFileID, blobOfNewContent);
```

I get the following error:
**Execution failed: We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again. (line 13, file "Code") [8.215 seconds total runtime]**

Any clues as to what else I can try? Basically, I need to maintain the ID of the file and just update the contents every so often from other file.

```
function overwriteFile(blobOfNewContent, originalFileID) 
{
  var currentFile;
  currentFile = DriveApp.getFileById(originalFileID);    

  if (originalFileID != "") 
  {//If original File exsts
    Drive.Files.update({
      title: currentFile.getName(), mimeType: currentFile.getMimeType()
    }, originalFileID, blobOfNewContent);
  }
} 

function getNewestSlidesInFolderAndUploadToStaticFileID() 
{
  // fileID of file that is "Original File"
  var mainfileID = "some id";

  var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('Testing Slides');  
  var arryFileDates = [];
  var objFilesByDate = {};

  //find most recent file
  while (folders.hasNext())
  {
    var folder = folders.next();   
    var files = folder.getFilesByType("application/vnd.google-apps.presentation");

    while (files.hasNext())
    {
      var file = files.next();

      // Make sure the fileID is not the static file
      if (file.getId() != mainfileID)
      {      
        var fileDate = file.getLastUpdated();   
        objFilesByDate[fileDate] = file.getId(); //Create an object of file names by file ID  
        arryFileDates.push(file.getLastUpdated());
      } // end if id = mainfileID
    } //end while (files.hasNext())

    arryFileDates.sort(function(a, b) { return b - a});   
    var newestDate = arryFileDates[0];
    Logger.log('Newest date is: ' + newestDate);

    var newestFileID = objFilesByDate[newestDate];

    Logger.log('newestFile: ' + newestFileID);
    //return newestFile;
  }//while folders.hasNext()

  //Get the contents of the most recent file
  var newestFile = DriveApp.getFileById(newestFileID);
  var blob = newestFile.getBlob();

  overwriteFile(blob, mainfileID);

  //delete most recent file so that only the main file exists
  newestFile.setTrashed(true);  
}
```

I did find all this code here on stackoverflow and I just modified (hardcoded) some pieces for my needs. Thanks to the original coders for their assistance.

Comment: Have you tried this with non-GSuite mimetypes (e.g. .docx or .pptx)? Does it fail for only certain file IDs? Where are your links to the source questions?

Comment: I just tried it with an image and it works. Thanks for that suggestion. Any clues as to why the presentation mime_Type isn't working. At least, I have some place to start testing!

Comment: Google's internal products are not simple blobs. Probably you can use the appropriate REST API to update the core representation.

Comment: Know of any samples code for this? I can't get anything to work. TIA.